# Bold a particular word in Text - React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I need to replace the boldText `based on the index value` in the place of `{index}` and that word should be **bold**.

Example:

```
 {
  sentence: {0} and {1} are great
  boldText: ['You', 'Your Family']
 }
```

output:

**You** and **Your Family** are great.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a simple example to do that.

Hope that it will help you!

```js
const sample = {
  sentence: '{0} and {1} are great',
  boldText: ['You', 'Your Family']
};

const applyBoldStyle = text => text.sentence.replace(/\{(\d+)\}/g, (match, i) => `<b>${text.boldText[i]}</b>`);

console.log(applyBoldStyle(sample));
```

Please note that you can pass whatever you want to fit react-native or whatever. Here I pass simple HTML with `<b>` tag, what matters here is the `replace` function. Make it return whatever you want.

With react-native, you probably want to use the following:

```
const sample = {
  sentence: '{0} and {1} are great',
  boldText: ['You', 'Your Family']
};

const applyBoldStyle = text => {
  let numberOfItemsAdded = 0;
  const result = text.sentence.split(/\{\d+\}/);
  text.boldText.forEach((boldText, i) => result.splice(++numberOfItemsAdded + i, 0, <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{boldText}</Text>););
  return <Text>{result}</Text>;
};
```

Comment: `<b>You</b> and <b>Your Family</b>` its completely appearing as a text. Not applying as bold style.

Comment: It appears because it is printed in the console and it's not an HTML render. I've added some react code, feel free to test it.

Comment: Wow! Great Stuff. Learnt something new. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an string `You and Your Family are great` and an array of element to bold `[0, 1]`, you can do something like this:

```
const   string = 'You and Your Family are great';
const   myArray = [0, 2];
const   mySplitedString = string.split(' ');
const   toReturn = mySplitedString.map((eachWord, index) =>
{
    if (myArray.indexOf(index) !== -1)
        return (<Text key={`text_${index}`} style={{fontWeight: '900'}}>{eachWord}</Text>);
    return (<Text key={`text_${index}`}>{eachWord}</Text>);
})
return (toReturn);
```

And then render the toReturn value.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version I came up with if you want to style words or individual characters at their index in react/javascript.

```
replaceAt( yourArrayOfIndexes, yourString/orArrayOfStrings )
```

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/ov7zxp9mjq

```
function replaceAt(indexArray, [...string]) {
    const replaceValue = i => string[i] = <b>{string[i]}</b>;
    indexArray.forEach(replaceValue);
    return string;
}
```

And here is another alternate method

```
function replaceAt(indexArray, [...string]) {
    const startTag = '<b>';
    const endTag = '</b>';
    const tagLetter = i => string.splice(i, 1, startTag + string[i] + endTag);
    indexArray.forEach(tagLetter);
    return string.join('');
}
```

And another...

```
function replaceAt(indexArray, [...string]) {
    for (let i = 0; i < indexArray.length; i++) {
        string = Object.assign(string, {
          [indexArray[i]]: <b>{string[indexArray[i]]}</b>
        });
    }
    return string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this [react-native-highlight-words](https://github.com/clauderic/react-native-highlight-words) 

It's so simple and useful!
Here is the usage example from the documentation:

```
import Highlighter from 'react-native-highlight-words';

  <Highlighter
      highlightStyle={{backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}
      searchWords={['and', 'or', 'the']}
      textToHighlight="The dog is chasing the cat. Or perhaps they are just playing?"
  />
```