# How to display a text body with html tags, in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have an api that returns some texts from a popular website in my country. You can think of these texts as user's comments. But these comments can includes links ( tag) and also like "< /hr />" tags. Some of them looks like this;

[image]

so basically I want an idea about how to manage these kind of texts when we want to display it in React Native?

Comment: Do you want to delete the html tags from the text you're getting?

Comment: There's no clean and easy solution for that unfortunately. The easiest would be to render the html text within a webview. But the efficient is to try to get the tags and its content with regex and replace it with a react native component. Like this answer does: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51423393/5793132 But the problem here would be the attributes (like `href`), you should get the attrs and the content with regex and replace it after, which would be a bit hard. For the self closing tags you can just replace the tag with a RN component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will answer your question:

```js
const regex = /<[^>]*>/mgi
const text = "A text with <strong>html tags</strong>"
const text_without_tags = text.replace(regex, "")
// text_without_tags = 'A text with html tags'
```

The [regular expresion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) gets every tags in a string (with their attributes). The method `replace` in this example will replace the tags that the regex got by `""` (so nothing).

However, if you want to keep the tags, but only change them into JSX tags, use [react-html-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser).

I'm not sure if I understood your goal.

Comment: this is great, what I wanna do is for example where there is a link like a href, I need to be able parse it to <Text> element and I also need to href value since I will link it

Comment: This should be possible with Regular Expresions (regex). However, could you try `react-html-parser` ?

Comment: I will try and I also found react-native-html-parser and we'll see

Answer (score 0):

You can use [react-native-rich-editor](https://github.com/wxik/react-native-rich-editor) to display the text if you want to keep the html tags